# Unknown activity and minus rep

Tags: discussion

I just logged in today and saw below changed in my rep:[image: unknown activity]

What does this mean? What does "removed" means? and why did i get -2 in rep?

Comment: *"Removed"* means the post was... removed (deleted). And if you'd got +2 for e.g. an accepted edit on it, that rep is now removed too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You got +2 reputation for editing that post (approved edit suggestion).

That post was subsequently deleted, removing the reputation you got from editing it.

Comment: Thanks. so that means they disregarding your effort in editing a question? * sob sob *

Comment: @Ceeee Its better to edit questions that are salvageable to not waste your effort on a deleted question. The rep is just a small bonus from that.

Comment: Some posts are just badly written in english which may be edited and might be a salvageable post. What if someone edited a question that for many of us find it unsalvageable (because its badly written in english) but turns out to be a valid question then effort and +2 is good. what if we edited another question but turns out that its really bad even if we correct all the grammar, then our effort is wasted but we helped the community to identify if its good or bad. For me keeping the community clean by cleaning real "garbage" is better than cleaning an already clean post

Comment: Except of course for spams and shitty posts. We don't have to edit them obviously